# Multiple Database Migration improve performance

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application where each user gets their own database where each database has the same schema.

I have a script that performs migrations in this fashion:

1. SHOW databases
2. Iterate through databases
3. Execute sql statements

This can take a long time when there are complicated queries that take a lot of time (3 or more seconds)

Is there a way where I can run the sql statements for each database at the same time from one script? Is this dangerous/too resource intensive to do this?

The reason I want to do this, is to prevent downtime as much as possible.

Here is my script now:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
set_time_limit(0);
$sql = file_get_contents('../update.sql');
$sql_queries = explode(";", $sql);
$exclude_dbs = array('horde','phppoint_forums','phppoint_site','roundcube', 'pos', 'bntennis_site', 'mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "PASSWORD");
$show_db_query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SHOW databases');
$databases = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_db_query)) 
{ 
    if (!in_array($row['Database'], $exclude_dbs))
    {
        $databases[] = $row['Database'];
    }
}

foreach($databases as $database)
{
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
    echo "Running queries on $database\n***********************************\n";
    foreach($sql_queries as $query)
    {
        if (!empty($query))
        {
            echo "$query;";
            if (!mysqli_query($conn, $query))
            {
                echo "\n\nERROR: ".mysqli_error($conn)."\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "\n\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Running a query for each database in one action is very risky and will be a resource hog.  It is better to separate the queries or actions and then call each one.  Or you could just call a method to copy main data to one database and then run queries against that and only query the otherwise databases when you need more information.  But to send complex queries to several databases at one time is never a good idea when looking at security and response time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the database will hold for that load but basically I would fork the process or spawn it into the background, depending on language.

For php you can fork the process for each database basically running the migrations in parallel.

Comment: yeah I am starting to think executing expensive queries on 200 databases at the same time might be a bad idea.